# Out of Memory issue with Finding Triplets Summing up to 0 from unsorted array and adding to List<int[]>

Tags: c#

I'm solving a problem where I need to find all triplets that add up to zero within an unsorted array of ints and return them as a List.

I can't figure out why Coderpad is giving me an Out of Memory error when I run this code. What am I missing?

Here is the prompt and logic:

Given an array of unsorted numbers, find all unique triplets in it that add up to zero.

Input: [-3, 0, 1, 2, -1, 1, -2]
Output: [-3, 1, 2], [-2, 0, 2], [-2, 1, 1], [-1, 0, 1]

Brute Force:

Find all trio combinations within array

O(N^3)

Approach:

Sort Array

Iterate through array in a for loop

Use two pointers on opposite ends on the remainder of the array

If element at input[i] + input[left] + input[right] < 0 => left++

If element at input[i] + input[left] + input[right] > 0 => right--

Else, add input[i], input[left], input[right] into List<int[]> result

Complexity:

O(N^2)
O(N)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] example = new int[] {-3, 0, 1, 2, -1, 1, -2};

        List<int[]> answer = FindUniqueTriplets(example);

        foreach (int[] combo in answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", combo));
        } 
    }

    public static List<int[]> FindUniqueTriplets (int[] input)
    {
        List<int[]> result = new List<int[]>();
        
        // Sort the array
        Array.Sort(input);
        
        // Iterate through array in a for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            // Use two pointers on opposite ends on the remainder of the array
            int left = i + 1;
            int right = input.Length - 1;

            while (left < right)
            {
                // If element at input[i] + input[left] + input[right] < 0 => left++
                if (input[i] + input[left] + input[right] < 0)
                {
                    left++;
                }
                // If element at input[i] + input[left] + input[right] > 0 => right--
                else if (input[i] + input[left] + input[right] > 0)
                {
                    right--;
                }
                // Else, add input[i], input[left], input[right] into result
                else
                {
                    result.Add(new int[] {input[i], input[left], input[right]});
                }
            }
        }                   
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: result has 33554432  items.  Left is 4 and right is 6.  So neither of the if statements are true and you are always falling into the last else.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend adding some formatting to the question to make it easier to read (I think some line breaks got lost or muddled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `else` case inside the `while` loop, we add an item to the array but the `while` condition remains `true` (because we didn't change the value of `left` or `right`), so the loop continues to run, constantly adding the same three items to the `result` variable.

To solve this, add a `break` statement to break out of the `while` loop when we add to `result`:

```
else
{
    result.Add(new[] { input[i], input[left], input[right] });
    break;
}
```

or increment the `left` variable (or decrement `right`, or both):

```
else
{
    result.Add(new[] { input[i], input[left], input[right] });
    left++;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I also noticed that instead of break, adding left++; right--; solves the issue as well while continuing to check for other combinations with input[i].

Comment: Yes, that's true. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a result, you enter an infinite loop and keep adding until you run out of memory. I believe you're missing a `break` after adding it the first time.

Comment: Awesome thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I also noticed that instead of break, adding left++; right--; solves the issue as well while continuing to check for other combinations with input[i].